# Is there an efficient algorithm to find the "maximal connected set"?

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode

Given a 2D table of boolean values describing connections between pairs of nodes, is there an efficient way to find the largest subset of nodes in which all nodes are connected to all nodes?

Example with 6 nodes:

[image]

In this case, the "maximal connected set" is {node1, node4, node5}. Although node0 is connected to node2 and node3, node2 and node3 are not connected, so do not form a "connected set".

This is a small example, but I am interested in a general algorithm that could in principle be applied to very large tables.

In case it helps, my objective is to reproduce the *M<sub>n</sub>* values from Table I of this paper: Sarwate, D.V., and M.B. Pursley, "Crosscorrelation Properties of Pseudorandom and Related Sequences," Proc. IEEE, Vol. 68, No. 5, May, 1980, pp. 583-619.

I will be coding this in MATLAB, but am also fairly fluent in C/C++.

**EDIT**: Here is the table I want to reproduce results from:
[image]

- The 1st and 2nd columns aren't really important here (just describe lengths of the codes).
- The 3rd column is what I referred to as number of "nodes".
- The 4th column is a measure of error if you use all nodes (regardless of
  whether they're "connected" or not).
- The 6th column is the (minimum) error if only the "maximal connected set" is used.
- The 5th column, *M<sub>n</sub>* describes the number of nodes in the maximal connected set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is equivalent to - in fact, it could even be considered as a restatement of - the *maximal clique problem* in graph theory. Graph theory deals with exactly the structures you are talking about: nodes connected together, which are called graphs, and one way to represent them is what you have above, which is called an adjacency matrix.

A "maximal clique" is exactly what you've described: the largest subset of the graph's nodes whom are such that each node is connected to every other.

This problem is "NP-complete", which is basically a whole class of problems that are widely conjectured, but not proven, to not be solvable "efficiently": in particular, what that means is that with regard to the strongest conjectures made in that vein, which *have plausibility arguments*, these problems, at bare minimum, are *exponentially* time-consuming. That is, you essentially can't do much better than just exhaustively searching your whole graph, at least in the general case. That said, for a table this small, an exhaustive search of all the nodes and connections is still essentially instant even for a home computer, but on anything more than a relatively small scale, will become infeasible even for a supercomputer.

Comment: Thank you for your very fast answer. I will read up on "maximal cliques". I have updated my question to clarify that I would be interested in larger tables in practice.

Comment: @Harry : Thanks. How much larger are you thinking? That said, given that you have referred a paper with already-computed values, it suggests that, given they were able to compute them, perhaps you might be either looking at the wrong problem or there are additional constraints on the problem domain that would then make it efficient, provided their data set was "large" in your sense.

Comment: The paper is from 1980, so computational power certainly shouldn't be a barrier in reproducing their results (though my lack of understanding could be). Their Table I only lists a few results and I would be interested to generate a few more (only out of interest). Their last result has 2048 nodes, but I don't think there is an upper bound in theory.

Comment: @Harry : Yeah, I can't check the paper at the moment, so I suspect they're doing something different from what you might be thinking. Can you post an excerpt of just the table? Or even just what it is supposed to tabulate, e.g. the table title/caption? What is M_n?

Comment: @The_Symphathizer : I have added the table at the end of my question. I am not sure if this will tell you what you need to know. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @Harry : I finally got access to the paper. On first cursory examination, it looks like that the problem has structure and isn't simply finding a maxclique in a totally arbitrary graph. Because of that, it likely falls into a special case that is easier to solve than the general case and it looks like they detail the method as well.

Comment: Namely, they're doing statistical tests on sequences generated from _pseudo-random_ generators, not truly random, and seem to be exploiting the deep characteristics of this specific pseudo-random method (here a linear feedback shift register, or LFSR, a rather simplistic, but still has its uses, PRNG by today's standards at least).